# Matching self reported and official titles

Tags: sas, match, fuzzy-search

I am currently breaking my head over a problem concerning matching of a dataset containing self reported job titles (and thus messy, incoherent and with loads of orthographic errors) with a standardised list of official titles in SAS.

In a condensed form lets say I have the following list of standardised titles:

```
machine engineer
machine assistant
machine mechanic
machine operator
```

And a snapshot of the self-reported titles with some of the common problems:

```
Machine engineer
machine engineer at ABC machine company
mechanic for agricultural machines
mchaine assistant
machine operator/conductor
```

Often these self-reported titles contain a company name and a sector that is not of interest as well as errors in spelling. First I was thinking of a fuzzy matching, but with the COMPGED function the edit distance would be very high for the entries that for example contain the company. The problem itself contains approximately 1,400 standardised job titles and more than 170,000 distinct self-reported titles coming from a total of roughly 1 million entries. Obviously it would be too optimistic to expect that all titles could be matched, but any method of getting closer would be of great help. What I am aiming for would essentially look like this:

```
ID  self_reported                                   standardised

 1  Machine engineer                                machine engineer
 2  machine engineer at ABC machine company         machine engineer
 3  mechanic for agricultural machines              machine mechanic
 4  mchaine assistant                               machine assistant
 5  machine operator/conductor                      machine operator
```

Is there any method that is able to somewhat deal with the multitude of problems that can arise in this matching problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you're licensing Text Miner I think you're not really going to get very far with the size of problem you're looking at here.  Look around online for text matching resources if you want to know more about this problem.

Comment: I like the answer here from FriedEgg. Otherwise you're looking for the terms 'fuzzy matching' or 'probabilistic linkage' and you can search those terms on here or lexjansen.com for example code. This isn't an easy problem and as you know you won't get 100% match.

Comment: ´COMPGED´ might be usefull